# XORing Algorithm Outputs To Guard Against Breakthroughs

Tags: hash, mac, multiple-encryption

My question is how safe is XORing two algorithm outputs together...

...For Symmetric Encryption:

- Master key from CSPRNG ==> `MK`
- HKDF-Expand(`MK`, info="AES") ==> AES Key
- HKDF-Expand(`MK`, info="ChaCha20") ==> ChaCha20 Key
- Ciphertext = `Message` XOR `AES-256-CTR_STREAM(AES Key, counter)` XOR `ChaCha20_STREAM(ChaCha20 Key, counter)`
- The counter will increment per message.

...For Hashes:

- SHA3_512(message) XOR SHAKE256(message, 512)

... And lastly for MACs:

- Create separate keys like in the encryption example (KMAC Key, Poly 1035 Key)
- KMAC(message, KMAC Key) XOR Poly1305(message, Poly1305 Key)

How safe are these constructions?

If this question it too broad because of the separate algorithm types please let me know and I'll edit.

Comment: If I had to pick an encryption algorithm which needed to secure 1000 years in the future, it would be ChaCha20 with a 256-bit key. That's not an opinion I'm actually qualified to have, but I base it on ChaCha having so few "moving parts" to exploit, support for 256-bit keys, and 20 rounds appearing to be extremely, extremely conservative.

Comment: I understand that all the algorithms are very secure and are expected to be in the future, but I'm wandering for in the case that one of the ciphers has an unexpected weakness discovered, then there can be a transition period of ciphers without there ever being a completely broken construction. For example, say we use `ChaCha20 XOR AES`, and `AES` has a flaw found, then for the time being, the construction is safe, whilst we transfer to `ChaCha20 XOR Serpent` for example.

Comment: Commented before because it wasn't directly important to the question. But the reason why I picked 1000 years is because of breakthroughs in physics enabling some new form of computing. I'm imagining fantastical sci-fi disregard for the known laws of physics and beyond-Kardashev-II civilizations. With that level of hedging, I wouldn't assume that any existing algorithm could then be relied upon. I don't think ChaCha20 has an expiration date when it comes to cryptanalysis in a world where 256-bit security is still considered safe.